# Which is the right way to generate a Podfile in flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-dependencies, podfile

For me, there are two ways to generate a pod file after deleting it
the first one is by running flutter pub get and then a pod file will be generated in the following form after some editing

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics' #ATTENTION PLEASE SHOULD I ADD THESE PODS HERE?
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      t.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0’
      end
    end
end
```

then running pod install

---

And the other implementation is when I run pod init i get the following after some editing:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

end

post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      t.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0’
      end
    end
end
```

then run pod install...
which is the right way to use flutter and build and run ios apps, as I am so confused and I can't run my app in ios form.
more details are in this [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/5011#issuecomment-782741918) I would be pleased if someone helps me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, in flutter you don't have to install the pods in your Podfile like
`pod 'Firebase/Messaging'` just put them in your pubspec file then just run `pod clean` then delete your Podfile then run `flutter pub get` and flutter will generate the Podfile for you, then you should just uncomment the second line and run `pod install` then run your app

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to delete `pod` folder and run
`flutter pub get` and then `pod install`?

Comment: It will generate the first podfile mentioned.